# I want to know can i give name to enum declared in Swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor, swagger-codegen

I have an Enum like below

```yaml
enum:
 - Male
 - Female
```

but internally i want this as `F` and `M`? like if i print Male it should print M not male

Comment: think fist, how would you passa an ENUM to your API?

Comment: in api also i want value as M but for front end i want it as Male

Comment: so would be a string dont you think?

Answer (score 0):

Since in your comments you speak about the frontend, I guess you mean that when you show this values you want to show "Female" and "Male", instead of F and M, that part goes beyond what swagger does.

What you need to put now is the values the API expects to receive which are, as you stated, M and F.

```
properties:
  gender:
    type: string
    description: Gender of the person
    enum:
    - M
    - F
```

Considering the [data types listed in the spec](https://swagger.io/specification/#data-types-12) your best choice seems to be `string`.

How you show the data in the frontend is a completely different matter and you should implement something to display the enum values however you decide is best.

There are a couple of issues open in the swagger spec about enums that have a bit to do with what you want: [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/348) and [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/681).